# add fields to polymorphic devise user rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, polymorphism

I have a rails app, using devise for users.  I have 2 types of users that share some fields and then have their own.  I made polymorphic models for the 2 types. When I added fields to the base devise user, the form for adding a new user doesn't seem to be recognizing the new fields.

**devise user**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  belongs_to :meta, polymorphic: true
end
```

**polymorphic artist model**

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :user, as: :meta, dependent: :destroy
    has_and_belongs_to_many :artist_expertises
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :user

    has_many :connections
    has_many :teachers, through: :connections
end
```

**overwriting devise registrations**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    private

    def sign_up_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end

    def account_update_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
    end

end
```

**routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

...
  resources :artists
  resources :teachers
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
...
end
```

Then on the following _form that is used in the new page for an artist is fine for the email and password fields from devise by default. the next user_fields.label for the :first_name field that I added to the users table errors with (undefined local variable or method `user_fields' for #<#:0x007f9c81b3a108>
Did you mean?  number_field)

**views/artist/_form.html.erb  (rendered in the new view)**

```
<%= form_for(setup_artist(@artist)) do |f| %>
    <% if @artist.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@artist.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this artist from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% @artist.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.fields_for :user do |user_fields| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= user_fields.label :email %>
      <%= user_fields.text_field :email %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= user_fields.label :password %>
      <%= user_fields.text_field :password %>
    </div>
    <% end %> 

    <div class="field">
      <%= user_fields.label :first_name %><br />
      <%= user_fields.text_field :first_name %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= user_fields.label :last_name %><br />
      <%= user_fields.text_field :last_name %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :inspiration %><br>
      <%= f.text_area :inspiration %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label "Area of Expertise" %><br />
      <%= f.collection_check_boxes :artist_expertise_ids, ArtistExpertise.all, :id, :name do |b| %>
      <div class="collection-check-box">
        <%= b.check_box %>
        <%= b.label %>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>


    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

welp, I'm a ding dong. had the <% end %> before I added the user fields.
Thanks for the help ya bing bongs.